# stylesheet reference to fonts.googleapis.com occasionally seems to fail loading or gets corrupted

Tags: vue.js, google-api, vuetify.js

My project was started with the Vue CLI + Vuetify new project templates.  This is the standard font loading statement in index.html:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
```

99% of the time my users have no problems, but on desktop safari (newest version) occasionally the fonts don't load and users see different fonts.  The situation can't be fixed unless the user completely clears all website data for my site using "manage site data".  I've not been able to find any error messages in the console, and everywhere I can think to look (sources / network tab in safari dev settings) all look fine.  Have only been able to reproduce this weird state once on my dev machine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest use font-display `swap` for your case. As you will experience slow loading time as informed in Google Font's embed font notice.

`<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">`

**Font swap period**

> If the font face is not loaded, any element attempting to use it must
>   render a fallback font face. If the font face successfully loads
>   during this period, it is used normally.

Comment: interesting, thanks for pointing me to that.  do you think not using this could cause a situation where a user would permanently not get the new font until fully clearing browser cache?  I would have thought on the next refresh it should properly get the correct font?

Comment: I believe that would be good approach to accomodate more network quality ranges of the site visitors.